# Incorrect parsing of response from GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am new to `GraphQL` and am using it in a project built around `Next.js` and using `Redux` for state management. I have a rather complex query which is yielding perfectly fine results in the `GraphiQL` interface. 
**Even in the `Network` tab of `DevTools` the `/graphql` call seems to have a perfect response as per the structure asked in the query.** However, data that `ApolloProvider` is making available in the state (`Redux Store`) is being parsed in a weird manner. Am seeing a lot of keys (all the object nesting 
 is getting lost) like

```
$Item:<some_id>.image:Object
$Item:<some_other_id>.artist:Object
$ROOT_QUERY.suggestions:Object
```

In GraphiQL, am seeing a perfectly fine single `JSON` object, but `Apollo` seems to be parsing it incorrectly and am getting lots of key-value pairs in `data`.

Am using straightforward code in my `React` component to fetch:

```
export default graphql(fetchDataQuery, {
  props: ({ data }) => ({
    data,
  }),
})(ComponentName);
```

Here, if I try to log `this.props.data`, all data seems to be fine. What am I missing ? How can the correct data be put into the `Redux` store ?

My ApolloClient creation code is as follows:

```
function create() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: !process.browser,
    networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
      uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
      headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      },
      opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
      },
    }),
  });
}
```

If any other information is needed, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Apollo automatically normalizes the data it receives through queries -- you can read more details about the process [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/core/how-it-works.html#normalize).

To access the data provided by your query, you will need to utilize the `graphql` HOC component Apollo provides. This works pretty much like Redux's `connect` HOC and allows you to map any data you receive from a specific query to props in the wrapped component.

If you need to use both HOCs for a component, integrating them is fairly straightforward as well. You can read more about integrating Redux with Apollo [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/redux.html).